# ASUS K75V UEFI Windows 8

Tags: windows, boot, uefi

I want install Windows 8 on my ASUS K75V with UEFI Boot, but I don't know why, but it is still installing with Legacy boot.

How can I change this ? Thanks, very much.

ehm... will be UEFI boot on win 8 faster than legacy boot on win 7? I have Core i7 3630QM, 8gb ddr3, 128gb kingston hyperx ssd.

Comment: In general, booting Windows 8 is faster than booting Windows 7.

Comment: open the boot manager of the laptop (normally F11 or F12) and select here DVD/USB boot via UEFI.

Comment: Or disable the legacy boot in BIOS completly thus only allowing booting to uefi.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried all what you said, but problem was in BIOS. I don't have options with UEFI in my BIOS - just general enable/disable UEFI BOOT, but when I enabled, it was hidden and I can't do anything with UEFI. When I downgrade my BIOS to older version, UEFI booting is working. Thanks for reply :)

Comment: You cannot have both BIOS and UEFI firmware on your motherboard.  There were some products that advertised it had both, but based on the age of the CPU and when it was released, that doesn't apply to your device.